# How can I remove special characters in posted data

Tags: html, regex, django

I need to remove special characters from the posted data. It may be possible by using Regular Expressions or may be other. How to strip the special characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use form validation for this http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/:

```
class MyForm(Form):

    def clean_<fieldname>(self):
        #your validation
```

And here is the method you can use to remove special characters :

```
import re
cleaned_field_value = re.sub(r'\W', '', raw_field_value)
```

However, this will not remove underscores if you need to remove them, use the regular exp :

```
r'\W|_'
```

instead.

EDIT :

If it is just a textbox, so forget the form validation method... But I guess the `sub` method is still valid.

Comment: But my textbox is not in a form. And also I am not validating the form. Also I want only to remove the "(quotation) symbols.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more precise ? Do you "simply" need to remove quotation marks ? Or quotation marks around a text ? Can you give more details ?!